# Move a subject from the middle of a sentence to its beginning

Tags: grammaticality, sentence, writing-style, sentence-patterns

Is it grammatically and stylistically correct to use sentences like the following ones, in nonfiction writing (technical, business, scientific):

- Apples - put in the green boxes.
- Lemons - put on the yellow shelves.

Instead of:

- Put apples in the green boxes.
- Put lemons on the yellow shelves.

Comment: They are not "sentences", according to the "rules" of English.  But they would be legitimate in the proper context -- say a list of instructions to workers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list of instructions would probably not repeat the word "put." That action would be shown at the top. But for other forms of written and spoken English, the full sentences in your second set are preferable.